# Can't add context menu item to .mp4 file

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

So for the past 30minutes I've been searching on the internet and seen some possible solutions, but none of them seem to work.

I know how to do it because I've successfully added my context menu item to the astrix (*), but I just can't find where to place my key to only show up on .mp4 files.

So far I've tried:

- .mp4
- WMP11.AssocFile.MP4
- WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG
- mpegfile
- MPlayer

---

**EDIT SINCE IT IS MARKED AS DUPLICATE:**

I like how you set this as duplicate. But I used that method and it still didn't work. SO THAT IS WHY I ASKED IT. So if you are so kind to mark it as duplicate please help me then, I also see that someone upvoted this post so I'm not alone!

Comment: @DavidPostill, I like how you set this as duplicate. But I used that method and it still didn't work. SO THAT IS WHY I ASKED IT. So if you are so kind to mark it as duplicate please help me then, I also see that someone upvoted this post so I'm not alone!

Comment: It was marked a dupe because it appears to ask the same question. The solution there not working doesn't make the question different.  The question doesn't include any info on your being aware of the other thread, exactly what you tried & how, and the nature of "didn't work".  There's nothing here to distinguish what might be different in your case or to diagnose why the answer didn't work.  Absent that, asking the same question again will produce the same answer again.  If this is a different problem, the question needs to clearly differentiate it and provide enough information to solve it.